# "Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually"

Tags: magento, caching

Magento admin throws an exception:

> Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually

It is fresh instalation on new hosting package.

Comment: Not a direct answer to this question, but for me this post provided the answer to your issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93740/could-not-determine-temp-directory-please-specify-a-cache-dir-manually

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Usually it will happen in shared web hosting, but also some times on individual server, if the permission of tmp folder is set wrong.

Many people suggest to modify the file:
`/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` to fix this problem. However, it may be a trap when you upgrade your Magento, as this file resides as core file of Magento. I recommend to use Magento's override feature.

Firstly, copy `/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` to `/app/code/local/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`.

Then on line 91 or near this line, you will find:

```
'cache_dir' => null,
```

Change to:

```
'cache_dir' => "var/tmp/",
```

You can change the cache folder wherever you want.
Now create a directory named tmp(or whatever name you have given above) under var folder and change the permission to **777** if necessary.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work? Changing it directly in the /lib/ file does work as a proof the folder is there with permissions etc but when in the /app/ directory it has no effect. Have tried re running setup:di:compile but not sure if that is right

Comment: Hi @tim-baker, my solution is tested for Magento version 1.x. I think you are searching for the solution in Magento 2.x.

Comment: I am indeed, would it be a override in the normal way for magento 2?

Comment: Never mind, got the answer! (php.ini) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93740/could-not-determine-temp-directory-please-specify-a-cache-dir-manually

Comment: perfect solution great job @Mohit Kumar Arora

Answer (score 6):

This is only the permission issue. Just set the 777 permission to the cache directory and you are all done. try it.

For more details you can follow the link.

When ever you set the permission be sure it is recurrsively set..

chmod 777 -R /var/cache

this is the function

```
    public function getTmpDir()
        {
            $tmpdir = array();
            foreach (array($_ENV, $_SERVER) as $tab) {
                foreach (array('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP', 'windir', 'SystemRoot') as $key) {
                    if (isset($tab[$key])) {
                        if (($key == 'windir') or ($key == 'SystemRoot')) {
                            $dir = realpath($tab[$key] . '\\temp');
                        } else {
                            $dir = realpath($tab[$key]);
                        }
                        if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                            return $dir;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $upload = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
            if ($upload) {
                $dir = realpath($upload);
                if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                    return $dir;
                }
            }
            if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
                $dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
                if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                    return $dir;
                }
            }
            // Attemp to detect by creating a temporary file
            $tempFile = tempnam(md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)), '');
            if ($tempFile) {
                $dir = realpath(dirname($tempFile));
                unlink($tempFile);
                if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                    return $dir;
                }
            }
            if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('/tmp')) {
                return '/tmp';
            }
            if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('\\temp')) {
                return '\\temp';
            }
            Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually');
        }
```

defined in file lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php

http://www.webtechnologycodes.com/magento-error-could-not-determine-temp-directory-please-specify-a-cache_dir-manually/

Answer (score 4):

1. Create `tmp` folder in root of your magento installation with 777 permissions.
2. Open `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`
3. Find `$_options` property and change line: `'cache_dir' => null`, to `'cache_dir' => 'tmp'`,
4. Refresh page.

Comment: NOTE: if compilation is turned ON, then step 5. Open includes/source/Zend_Cache_Backend_File.php and make same changes as in File.php file. Then run compilation process again.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `info.php` and check for the path beneath `upload_tmp_dir` to be writable for the webserver.

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Otherwise set the path in your hosting environment.
Beware that this setting can not be placed within `.htaccess` files but some hosters allow individual `php.ini` files to be placed in your `docroot`:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /path/to/docroot/var/tmp/
```

Comment: this should be right answer instead of changing magento core files.